# Not able to show p:editor which is hidden from javascript in primefaces

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I have a p:editor like this.

```
<p:editor value="#{manageBean.profile.summary}" style="display:none;" id="txtPS" />

<i class="fa fa-edit" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="editThis('formID:txtPS')"></i>
```

My javascript function is:

```
function editThis(lblshow)
{ 
 document.getElementById(lblshow).style.display="inline";
}
```

By default editor will be hidden. When i click the icon, editor need to be shown. But it is not been shown.

Any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know, it´s an old issue, but here my solution:

Instead of using inline style, set display:none with a js function after the site has loaded.

```html
<p:editor value="#{manageBean.profile.summary}" id="yourId" />

<i class="fa fa-edit" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="display(yourId)"></i>

<!-- Insert the script at the end of your body -->

<script>
  window.onload = function display() {
    var yourId = document.getElementById("yourId");
    yourId.style.display = "none";
  }
  function display(ele) {
    if (ele.style.display == "none") {
        ele.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Additional, if you don´t want your user to see any of the content, that should be hidden, just use the css visibilty attribute as inline-stlye. Don´t forget to make the editor visible again in your script.

```html
<p:editor value="#{manageBean.profile.summary}" style="visibility: hidden;" id="yourId" />

<i class="fa fa-edit" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="display(yourId)"></i>

<!-- Insert the script at the end of your body -->

<script>
  window.onload = function display() {
    var yourId = document.getElementById("yourId");
    yourId.style.display = "none";
  }
  function display(ele) {
    if (ele.style.display == "none") {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        ele.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rendered` tag instead of css style:

```
<p:editor value="#{manageBean.profile.summary}" rendered="#{manageBean.renderEditor} id="txtPS"/>
```

Then use `<p:remoteCommand>` to call your bean from javascript

```
<p:remoteCommand name="myRemote" actionListener="#{manageBean.modifyRenderEditor}" update="txtPS"/>
```

Your javascript:

```
function editThis(lblshow)
{ 
 myRemote();
}
```

And Java:

```
private renderEditor=false;
public void modifyRenderEditor(){
   this.renderEditor=!this.renderEditor;
}
```